# What does "Rarest" mean on the badges display?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

What does *Rarest* mean in the *Badges* section of your *Profile* tab?

[image: Badges section with the 3 *Rarest* labels circled]

To whom are they indicating to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rarest = Not many other users have this badge = Maybe a lot of other people have this badge, but it's still less people than how many people have these other badges

So the reason that they show the rarest badges is because most users would want to know which badge(s) they have that most other people haven't been able to earn. Same goes for viewing other people's profiles.

The more a badge is given out, the less "valuable" it can be seen as in SE's "badge marketplace". So the "rarest" of the rarest badges are seen by most people as the most valuable. Since they are the "toughest" to earn.

Comment: Is there a exact number to define rarest?In other words, if the times of a badge being awarded is less than the exact number, it is a rarest badge.

Comment: @xshsinap I think it is `select top(3) * from badge where badge in (badges_you_have) order by count_of_people_who_have_that_badge asc`, so as other people earn a badge, it becomes less rare, but there is no "magic number" that determines rarity.

Answer (score 4):

It is the least awarded badge (to others) on that specific site that you have.

For example, if you have `Legendary`, on almost every site, that badge will not be given very frequently. See the [list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges): `Legendary` has been awarded only seven times!

The badges you see there should let you appreciate the particular badge a little more, as there are just a few people who have earned it.