# Is there a exact number to define "rarest" on the badges display?

Tags: support, badges

We can get the definition of "rarest" in the question([What does “Rarest” mean on the badges display?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254246/what-does-rarest-mean-on-the-badges-display/254248#comment830846_254248)). And I am still confused about its definition. Is there a exact number to define "rarest" on the badges display? In other words, if the times of a badge being awarded is less than the exact number, it is a rarest badge.